# Can i make a commad execute in background without producing any output?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Is there a way or an option to make a command run in the background without the need to wait for it to end to get the prompt back? (just like `mplayer` command to play a music file in the background and execute another command while listening to the music)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in a book about bash shell command:

```
setsid COMMAND &> /dev/null
```

Here is an example:

```
setsid mplayer "/home/naruto/Music/sfx_ctf_cap_pl.wv" &> /dev/null
```

In this way your command is completely invisible and I used it to listen to music while executing other commands in the terminal and the music will continue even if you close the terminal.

Comment: +1. This should have received more upvotes a long time ago especially since the top voted answer didn't have OP blessing.

Answer (score 5):

In a script, you can make a process run the background using:

```
COMMAND &
```

or

```
COMMAND & disown
```

this also works well if you want to run something from terminal and then close the terminal leaving the process running.

If you wish uou should also be able to hide the commands output (so it doesn't show in the background of a script) by using:

```
COMMAND >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

Comment: didn't work i tried both `&` and & `disown`
see here --> http://www.mediafire.com/view/9z4wac1y4f06ul5/naruto@naruto-Inspiron-N5110_~_018.png